# How can I remove poop?

Tags: pixel-piracy

How can I remove poop that builds up on my vessel in the new game pixel piracy? My fellow crew members keep pooping and it just sits there and it's really annoying.

Comment: It's not called a poop deck for nothing now is it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the PP wiki, you can stop poop build-up 2 ways. From reading the wiki (and not playing the game) it seems the cleaning option is the best.

source: http://pixelpiracy.gamepedia.com/Cleaning

Cleaning is a skill you acquire from a Bookstore. You teach the skill to a crew member and they clean the poo (and anything that causes "low morale").

Also you can acquire Diapers which stops a crew member from pooping entirely. The wiki page (http://pixelpiracy.gamepedia.com/Diaper) doesn't specify how long this effect lasts however so I still think cleaning is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy the cleaning skill in a town
2. save 5 TP with a pirate (by levelling up)
3. go to the YOUR CREW screen
4. click on a a pirate with 5 TP saved
5. click on 'passive equip'
6. Select the book on the left of which the tooltip says "cleaning"

Cleaning is a passive skill, meaning your pirate will perform the action without your intervention when on the ship.

Goodluck :)

Answer (score 1):

You also can sell poop, surprising enough.  I do not recall which store.

Comment: Is this in a recent update?

Comment: I haven't been playing that long, so it's fairly current.  I think it's the same place you buy/sell ship parts.